# Deploy Maven Project using Eclipse and Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, tomcat

I developed a very simple web service using eclipse for edit the code and tomcat 8.5 for deploy the web service. The Name of maven project is PruebaMaven and I can deploy that with success getting the classic hello world.

My problem is that when I want to access an a method associate to `localhost:8080/PruebaMaven/Services/Login/Validate`, the tomcat response is  `HTTP 404 - Not found`

The method that I want to access is a POST type, so I'm expecting that the response of the tomcat server be a `HTTP 405`.

I dont know if my thinking is correct or im wrong and the response of tomcat is apropiate. In the case that my thinking is correct, somebody know where is my issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your thinking is correct. It seems like you're using an incorrect URL. Did you try testing a simple GET method using the browser?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the log?